# Can I set a priority for images in a sitemap?

Tags: images, xml-sitemap

I have two diagrams on a page. One is a newer version of the other (the older image is still useful for some people, but most would refer to the newer image). The problem is that the older image is showing up in search results rather than the newer one.

Is is possible to set the newer image as a higher priority in an image sitemap? As far as I can see the `<priority>` tag can only be used within the `<url>` context and not within `<image:image>` context.

Or is there another way to tell Google that the newer image should be preferred?

Answer (score 3):

You can use structured data markup to specify which image you prefer as more meaningful to that webpage, so it is more likely to be used that image in SERP instead of the older one.

For https://schema.org/WebPage you can specify it via https://schema.org/image or https://schema.org/primaryImageOfPage

Consider this example that contains two images, the image of a news article (main) and the image of the logo of the publisher, the image `https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg` is specified as the main image of the article, while `https://google.com/logo.jpg` is bound to the publisher:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
  <meta itemscope itemprop="mainEntityOfPage"  itemType="https://schema.org/WebPage" itemid="https://google.com/article"/>
  <span itemprop="description">A wonderful article</span>
  <div itemprop="image" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
    <img src="https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg"/>
    <meta itemprop="url" content="https://google.com/thumbnail1.jpg">
    <meta itemprop="width" content="800">
    <meta itemprop="height" content="800">
  </div>
  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
    <div itemprop="logo" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ImageObject">
      <img src="https://google.com/logo.jpg"/>
      <meta itemprop="url" content="https://google.com/logo.jpg">
      <meta itemprop="width" content="600">
      <meta itemprop="height" content="60">
    </div>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Google">
  </div>
</div>
```

This helps Search Engines to understand your content better, and the image of the article is more likely to appear in SERP than the image of the logo of the publisher associated to the article.

Comment: Can you provide an example please.

Comment: @DocRoot I've added an example with two images and microdata.